# Python requests not responding

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Done a few small successful projects, been struggling to get the requests from this website fro ages - any tips?

UPDATE - Would like to get full beautiful soup request so I can start scraping the information from the tables

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/championship/marktwerte/wettbewerb/GB2")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
print soup
```

returning

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</hr></body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you want it to return? (update your question!)  (and welcome to SO!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *pretend to be a real user with a browser* and provide a `User-Agent` header:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/championship/marktwerte/wettbewerb/GB2", headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
})
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> r = requests.get("http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/championship/marktwerte/wettbewerb/GB2", headers={
...     "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
... })
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
>>> print(soup.title.get_text())
Top market values 15/16 - Championship - Transfermarkt
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much introducing me to user agents - will mark solved shortly

Comment: nice..beat me by a whisker!

Comment: I had the exact same problem with the same site, does it matter what kind of user agent I provide?

Comment: If you are still facing the same issue, check this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154114/python-request-get-fails-to-get-an-answer-for-a-url-i-can-open-on-my-browser/51154676

Answer (score 1):

There are some sites where **requests** fail to give response as many of them track if the request originating party is a browser or a bot.
So, let us look like a browser.

It can be done by modifying the header as follows:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
```

And then, just simply add this header your GET request as follow:

```
response = requests.get("https://example.com",headers=headers)
```

In total you will get:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
response = requests.get("https://example.com",headers=headers)
```